# Setting Metadata in Google Cloud Storage (Export from BigQuery)

Tags: file-permissions, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to update the metadata (programatically, from Python) of several CSV/JSON files that are exported from BigQuery. The application that exports the data is the same with the one modifying the files (thus using the same server certificate). The export goes all well, that is until I try to use the objects.patch() method to set the metadata I want. The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

```
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<bucket>/<file>?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

Obviously, this has something to do with bucket or file permissions, but I can't manage to get around it. How come if the same certificate is being used in writing files and updating file metadata, i'm unable to update it? The bucket is created with the same certificate.

Comment: Can you inspect that ACL on the object with `gsutil acl get` ?

Answer (score 1):

If that's the exact URL you're using, it's a URL problem: you're missing the `/o/` between the bucket name and the object name.